# Find the density for the random variable $Y=X_1+X_2$

Tags: probability-theory

Problem: Let $X_1, X_2$ be independent variables with uniform density on (-1,1). Find the density for the random variable $Y=X_1+X_2$.

My attempt using convolution:

$y_1=x_1+x_2, y_2=x_2 \Rightarrow x_1=y_1-y_1, x_2=y_2$

Since $g(y_1,y_2)=f(v(y)|J_v(y)|$, we know $\vec{v}(y_1,y_2) = (y_1-y_2,y_2)$ and $J_v=1$

To find $y_1$, we use $\int \frac{1}{2} dy_2$ and draw a diagram which shows $-1<y_1-y_2<1\Rightarrow y_2>y_1-1$ and $-1<y_2<1 \Rightarrow y_1-y_2>-1 \Rightarrow y_2<1+y_1$

So $\int_{-1}^{1+y_1} \frac{1}{2}dy_2$ if $-2<y_1<0$ and $\int_{y_1-1}^{1}\frac{1}{2}dy_2$if $0<y_1<2$

Therefore $y_1=$

$1+\frac{1}{2}y_1, -2<y_1<0$

$1-\frac{1}{2}y_1, 0<y_1<2$

Although convolution may not be an ideal method to perform this exercise, all of the examples that we have performed in class used method. I am not too sure about the diagram and the limits of integration. Any feedback on my attempt would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Convolution is quite suitable for sums. Some minor thing went wrong, your density has integral $2$. Right basic shape.

Comment: Are you stating that the density should be integral 2 or that my density has integral 2?

Comment: Your computed density cannot be correct, since if $f$ is a density function then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx=1$. Note that the integral of your computed density is $2$.

Comment: I thought that to be the case. Probability theory is not my strong suit, so I easily second guess myself. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Let our two random variables be $X$ and $Y$, and let $Z$ be their sum (I don't like subscripts). Then the density of $Z$ has shape $\int_D f_Y(z-x)f_X(x)\,dx$. In our case, the product of the densities is $\frac{1}{4}$ over the appropriate region. That's where your mistake is, you used $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: So switching $\frac{1}{2} to \frac{1}{4}$ and performing the same calculations should yield the correct densities for the region?

Comment: Yes, that will do it. I prefer a more explicit calculation that shows the geometry.